# Mixing inner and outer joins in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database with 3 tables. These tables represent membership information. I only want to retrieve results for groups that a specific user does NOT belong to. I'm not sure how to do this. Currently, I'm looking at the following:

```
SELECT
  g.*,
  a.*
FROM    
  GroupInfo g 
    INNER JOIN [Address] a ON a.[ID]=g.[AddressID]
    OUTER JOIN [GroupMembership] m ON m.[GroupID]=g.[ID]
WHERE
  m.[MemberID]<>@memberID
```

I'm concerned about accuracy and performance. Am I going the correct way?

Comment: does the query return the data you expect it to? What does the query execution plan show?

Comment: which group GroupInfo  or GroupMembership ? edit your question to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is

```
 Select * From GroupInfo g Join Address a
     On a.Id = g.AddressId
 Where Not Exists
    (Select * From GroupMembership 
     Where GroupID = g.GroupID
        And MemberID = @memberID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had questions about which of these two methods were faster, so I coded up a test. I created 2 tables, with the first also containing a foreign key to the second. I then made a million entries in table 1, and for about half of them made a linked entry in table 2.

I then ran both the join version and the subquery version. Both of them came up with the same values (good).

Interestingly enough, the also performed about exactly the same: about 20 seconds on my pitiful workstation. So it appears not to matter if you do it the way you proposed or another way. If it is possible for the joined table to have more than one value, I think that adding a top 1 to the sub query would be faster.

```
Select * From GroupInfo g Inner Join Address a
   On a.Id = g.AddressId
Where Not Exists
(Select Top 1 * From GroupMembership Where GroupID = g.GroupID
  And MemberID = @memberID)
```